# Left Join com LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

Eu tenho duas tabelas que vem de repositórios diferentes. Uma vem de uma API e tenho uma que vem do BD.

Eu já tenho as duas tabelas mapeadas para classes.

Quero selecionar todos os registros da tabela A que não estão na tabela B.

Usando um foreach seria algo como :

```
var result = new List<A>();

foreach (var item  in A)
{
    if (!B.Any(x => x.codigo == item.codigo))
    {
      result.Add(item );
    }
}
```

Eu tentei utilizar LINQ, mas não consegui sucesso.

Segue o código utilizado:

```
 var result = from a in ListA
            join b in ListB 
                on a.Codigo equals b.Codigo
                into tmpMapp
                     from m  in tmpMapp.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select a;
```

Em SQL seria

```
SELECT a LEFT JOIN b on a.Codigo = b.Codigo
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Com lambda seria algo assim:

```
 var result = ListA.Where(x => !ListB.Any(y => y.Codigo == x.Codigo));
```

Answer (score 2):

Eu faria deste modo

```
   var result= from a in ListA
               join b in ListB on a.Codigo equals b.Codigo into tmpMapp
               from m  in tmpMapp.DefaultIfEmpty()   
               select new { X = a, Y = m }
```

Mais informações podem ser obtidas através do site oficial da microsoft [aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins)

Answer (score 1):

Se as listas forem iguais você pode utilizar o Except.

Exemplo:

```
var result = ListA.Except(ListB);
```

ou ainda

```
var result = ListA.Where(x => !ListB.Exists(y => y.Codigo == x.Codigo));
```

Em alguns teste de desempenho o .Exists trabalha melhor do que o .Any

Espero que ajude.